# Trello now sanitizing URLs / disallowing custom url protocols?

Tags: trello, url, markdown

Up until *about* yesterday, I was able to add markdown links to a local application within the description area of my Trello Cards.

The application uses a custom url protocol to produce a url like the following:

`ttstudio://server:99//Product/dfct?recordID=3836`

I've been adding these references to my trello cards in the markdown format:

`[3836](ttstudio://server:99//Product/dfct?recordID=3836)`

where they'd render as

`<a href="ttstudio://server:99//Product/dfct?recordID=3836">3836</a>`

I just went back to one of these cards and noticed that the `href` now renders as

`<a href="#">3836</a>`

Which completely disables the link.

Changing to a standard protocol (http, https, ftp) renders the href correctly, which makes me think they've recently disabled custom/non-standard url protocols.

Anyone else experiencing this? Anyone know if this was changed on purpose and why? Is this documented anywhere that I can reference?

Their [development board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c) doesn't seem to indicate any changes were made, but I'm sure they don't post every change they make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-standard protocols were disabled as a security precaution, to prevent the use of dangerous URIs (e.g. `javascript:`) from being rendered.

See https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js/pull/52 for a pull request with more details.